# Connecting to SQL Server 2014 via console application does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I'm trying to read out values from my database. I'm pretty sure that the method I use is correct. Also my SQL Server 2014 allows remote access.

Nevertheless when I run my application I get an error.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

My code:

```
private void DatabaseUpgradeCheckForMSSQL()
{ 
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VBKSQL2014MSSQL\\MSSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=dwworkflowengine; User ID=sa; Password=<Password>;");
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Changesets", sqlCon);

    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sqlda.Fill(dtbl);

    foreach (DataRow row in dtbl.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row["Number"]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I need them because it is a string and i don't use a @ at the beginning of the string

Comment: Can you connect to that instance from a remote machine using SSMS and credentials used in a connection string?

Comment: Computer Mangement>Services and Applications\SQL Server Network Configuration\ Protocols for "YourSQLServer". Does TCP\IP Protocol enabled there?

Comment: I will try that and let you know!

Comment: @koviroli It is enabled

Comment: By default SQL Server listens for port 1433. Did you set inbound rule for that port in Firewall settings?

Comment: @AlexanderVolok remote access works!

Comment: @koviroli i added the inbound rule.. but still does not work. Btw. on this VM where i'm running the code the firewall is completely turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're connecting to the **default, unnamed** instance of SQL Server, which does have the internal "ID" of `MSSQLSERVER`, you **must not** use that internal ID as the instance name.

So instead of this:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VBKSQL2014MSSQL\\MSSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=dwworkflowengine; User ID=sa; Password=<Password>;");
```

try this:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VBKSQL2014MSSQL;Initial Catalog=dwworkflowengine;User ID=sa;Password=<Password>;");
```

And **please** - as a Best Practice - do ***NOT*** use the `sa` account for your work!! Use integrated security, or a separate account - `sa` should **NEVER** be used in your real life work!